# Inconsistent accessibility: property type - How to solve it if both class and list was public

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, listview

I have list of a custom made class cutting story short here is the code

```
    [DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(Offer))]
    [KnownType(typeof(Category))]
  public class HomePage
{
    private List<Category> _Categories;
    private List<Offer> _Featured;

    [DataMember]
    public List<Category> Categories { get { return _Categories; } set { _Categories = value; } }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Offer> Featured { get { return _Featured; } set { _Featured = value; } }
```

and here's my class

```
    public class Offers
{
    public string offerTitle {get; set;}
    public string offerDescription{get; set;}
    public string offerLocation{get; set;}

}
```

anyway when I try to build the project I get this error

> Inconsistent accessibility: property type  'System.Collections.Generic.List' is less accessible than property 'OffTag.HomePage.Featured'

Note: the list and the class both exists on a different file I dunno if this is the problem but I thought it worth mentioning as I'm developing a WCF web service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code compiles. In your example there is a class named Offers, but it has to be named Offer without "s" in the end. I removed Category as irrelevant.

```
        [DataContract]
        [KnownType(typeof (Offer))]
        public class HomePage {

            [DataMember]
            public List<Offer> Featured { get; set; }
        }

        internal class Program {
            private static void Main(string[] args) {
            }
        }

        public class Offer {
            public string offerTitle { get; set; }
            public string offerDescription { get; set; }
            public string offerLocation { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The general error is that "something in your class is visible to a scope that can't also see the type of the thing." In this case, the error means that you have a one of your properties (`Featured`) whose type is not public.

It's slightly misleading because the type is being described as `System.Collections.Generic.List`, but in reality it's going to be your `Offer` class that is not public. I note that you've shared the code for `Offers`, which is a different class - perhaps this is a simple typo?

Make sure `Offer` is public and the error will be remedied.